# The cookie banner doesn't stick to top

Tags: c#, html, css

In cshtml page I have used the following css style but it doesn't work as expected

```
  @@media screen and (max-width:600px){
              .cookie{
                       position:sticky;
                       top:0;
               }
   }
```

Comment: you are trying to apply this for desktop or mobile?

Comment: I am trying to apply this for mobile

Comment: Can you give us an insight to the actual environment? Maybe the values are just being overwritten.

Comment: Actually I am using the same code for desktop and mobile view..I have to stick cookie to bottom in desktop which works fine.for mobile I have stick to top where I am using media property to specify some pixel but it doesn't work

Comment: position sticky is not supported for all browsers. use position: fixed top: 0; instead

Comment: I found that using same class value "cookie" for desktop and mobile styling doesn't work. It works for desktop view but not for mobile view..Any idea on this ?